# Algorithms to brute force function inputs to find maximum

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, brute-force

There is a function like `CalculateProfit(decimal a, decimal b, float c, TimeSpan d)` and its each input parameter has `minimum`, `maximum` and `initial value` settings.

Its output is smooth but not linear, it has multiple peaks and falls. I want to bruteforce its inputs and find maximum possible output. How to optimize this without trying each possible combination? Maybe some kind of binary search?

I think the algorithm should use big delta steps at start to find most peaks and then tweak values with small deltas. Also I would bruteforce one input until I find best output and then try same for next inputs, then go back to tweaking first input and so on.

---

Update: the function is a complex algorithm which performs analysis on markets historical data (so it's not just a formula). Therefore I'm asking for some *bruteforce* optimizations, not trying to "solve" it as an equation.

Comment: Do you know `CalculateProfit` function and how it is being calculated in advance?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, I know but it's a complex algorithm inside so better think of it as a black-box thing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about partial differential equations solvers of 2 or more variables.
https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/min_max/min_max.html

Then you need to study one algorithm that can solve it, Finite Volume and Spectral Method are the most commonly used in Simulation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_partial_differential_equations

You can find easy solutions on Matlab if you are interested in just solving your problem. C# can call Matlab functions with some setup.

Comment: Are these methods applicable for a black-box function?

Comment: You have to read about FV algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_volume_method